# Issues about Binary Search

Tags: java

Trying to figure this out

Declared an Array
int[] iArray = {6, 12, 3, 9}

Ran Binary search for the number 9

return value is -2

Can someone explain to me why?

Do I have to Sort the array before I run the Binary Search in order to get the desired result?
I am confused lol

Comment: Yes, the array needs to be sorted first, before a binary search is attempted.

Comment: Gotcha, I am retarded lol. I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get a -2 because the 9 you are looking for would go between the first and second index of the list.  That is where it would have been inserted (between 6 and 9if it was sorted).

{[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int[],%20int%29](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29)}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, binary search only works on sorted data.   Can't explain why the -2 tho.